# Choosing Cartan subalgebra in a reductive subalgebra.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Suppose $L_1 \subset L_2$ are two Lie algebras over $\mathbb{C}$. $L_1$ is reductive, and $L_2$ is semisimple. They both have same rank. Can we find a $H$ to be Cartan subalgebra of $L_1$ and $L_2$ at the same time?
My attempt is to use definition and characterization of minimal Engel subalgebra in Humphreys Chapter 15 but does not work out well.

Appreciate any answer or hint.

Comment: If $L_2$ is $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$, then any one-dimensional subalgebra is abelian hence reductive and its own unique Cartan subalgebra, hence of rank $1$ (unless the definition of rank is different from what I think). But now if you take as $L_1$ the one-dimensional subalgebra generated by some nilpotent element, you have a counterexample.

Comment: Your example works! This statement appears in a paper so I thought it vacuously true. Anyway appreciate your answer!

Comment: As Torsten's example shows we need the centre of $L_1$ to be toral (i.e. consists of commuting semisimple elements). Together with the rank condition that should be sufficient.